# Dockerfile build image fail

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Project Structure:

```
Syslog.Sample
--docker.Sample
--Syslog.Sample
```

Project "docker.Sample" -> Add Docker support. This is the content of the generated Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["docker.Sample/docker.Sample.csproj", "docker.Sample/"]
RUN dotnet restore "docker.Sample/docker.Sample.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/docker.Sample"
RUN dotnet build "docker.Sample.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "docker.Sample.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "docker.Sample.dll"]
```

Run command "docker build ."

output fail context message:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/docker.Sample/docker.Sample.csproj" not found: not found
```

help me

Comment: Looks like this line is wrong:

`COPY ["docker.Sample/docker.Sample.csproj", "docker.Sample/"]`

Answer (score 8):

This is how I made it work: change this

`COPY ["docker.Sample/docker.Sample.csproj", "docker.Sample/"]`

to this

`COPY ["docker.Sample.csproj", "docker.Sample/"]`.

Remove the directory name of the csproj. For some reason the default Dockerfile created by VS is faulty.